# Как сгенерировать java код из uml диаграмм?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, uml

Как сгенерировать `java` код из `uml` `class diagram`, которые можно построить в `Intellij Idea`?

Answer (score 2):

Да, вот очень удобный инструмент http://www.visual-paradigm.com/features/code-engineering/

Answer (score 2):

В Intellij IDEA есть плагин UML Support (но только в Ultimate Edition).

Используйте <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> для активации контекстного меню.

---

Подробное описание функционала: [Working with Diagrams](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-diagrams.html)

Comment: Я как раз с помощью этого инструмента и создал диаграмму классов, но к сожалению не могу в документации найти, как сгенерить из нее код.

Comment: Сейчас нет под рукой IntelliJ Idea, но вроде бы можно правой кнопкой нажать на диаграмме или рядом с ней, в контекстном меню выбрать создание или обновление кода

Comment: А для `AndroidStudio` что-то такое есть?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб посмотрите http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123384/how-to-generate-class-diagram-uml-on-android-studio

Comment: @PavelParshin, то что там советуют уже, похоже, не работает( Ща пробую [отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33059580/3212712) решение

Answer (score 0):

Понадобится программа Enterprise Architector (ЕА):

1. Сохраните диаграмму классов в формате XML.
2. Откройте программу ЕА.
3. Выполните команду `import xml` (в зависимости от версии, может меняться: вкладка `Publish\import xml`).
4. Сформируется диаграмма; если с диаграммой всё нормально, то п. 5. Если нет, то корректируете и переходите в п. 5.
5. Во вкладке `Code\edit` `code\generate surrent with option`.

На выходе код.